# Can PowerShell load all functions from a script at the start of running a script (without using dot sourcing)?

Tags: powershell, abstract-syntax-tree

Here's the script that prompted this question. The idea was to see if it's possible to have a script load its own functions (without using dot sourcing) before they would have otherwise been defined. To be clear, I know this is not needed, I know of various methods to load functions for scripts, I'm just using this script to explore what's possible and get a better understanding of how PowerShell works under the hood:

```
Clear-Host

$ast = [Management.Automation.Language.Parser]::ParseInput((Get-Content $PSCommandPath -Raw), [ref]$null, [ref]$null)
$functionsList = $ast.FindAll({$args[0] -is [System.Management.Automation.Language.FunctionDefinitionAst]},$true)
foreach ($fn in $functionsList) { (New-Item -Path Function:$($fn.Name) -Value $fn.Body.Extent.Text.ToString() -Force | Out-Null) }

Write-Output '...'
Test-FunctionLoad2

function Test-FunctionLoad { 

    #

}

function Test-FunctionLoad2 { 

    Write-Output 'Test...'

}
```

The idea for this script is that by getting the script to parse itself it can load any functions defined later on within the script. In its current form, this partially works, but not fully. I was hoping that the call to Test-FunctionLoad2 would result in 'Test...' being displayed, but the script block for the function is shown instead.

Related to this, my best guess for why this might be happening is that the relevant scopes are not being updated properly. I'd like to be able to set a breakpoint in a PowerShell script and see the current state of the various available scopes, is this possible? In particular, is this possible for functions (I've seen methods for getting scope-specific variable values but I've not found a way to do this with functions)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is fine, but the issue is that `-Value` needs to be the [`ScriptBlock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.scriptblock?view=powershellsdk-7.3.0) from each [`ScriptBlockAst`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.language.scriptblockast?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0) instead of it's `string` representation, so, you can use [`.Body.GetScriptBlock()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.language.scriptblockast.getscriptblock?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0#system-management-automation-language-scriptblockast-getscriptblock) instead:

```
foreach ($fn in $functionsList) {
    New-Item -Path Function:$($fn.Name) -Value $fn.Body.GetScriptBlock() -Force | Out-Null
}
```

Another way to do it, if you're wondering what `New-Item` uses behind the scenes:

```
foreach ($fn in $functionsList) {
    $null = $ExecutionContext.SessionState.InvokeProvider.Item.New(
        'function:',
        $fn.Name,
        'Function',
        $fn.Body.GetScriptBlock())
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this Santiago, that worked. Just out of curiosity, how did you find out what New-Item was using behind the scenes? Did you look up the code on GitHub or is there another way to get at this information?

Comment: @ZenoArrow glad it helped. yup, I get it from reading the source: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/6d23f72defe83fd29d4a6c0344ddf68e2cbc9e4d/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Management/commands/management/Navigation.cs#L2013 `New-Item` would be using `InvokeProvider.Item.New` in the context of `this` (`PSCmdlet`) so its not exactly the same as `$ExecutionContext` but is as closer as we can get in a script level otherwise we would need to do it in an advanced function

Comment: Good info, but note that `-Value` _does_ accept a string (I haven't looked into the code in the OP), e.g. `New-Item function:foo -Value ' Get-Date '`

Answer (score 0):

The technique I'm using to be able to use functions that are defined later in the script, is simple and doesn't require use of the AST.

**Put all code into functions** and call the entry point function at the end of the script. This forces PowerShell to parse all code before running it.

```bash
function Invoke-Main {

    Clear-Host
    Write-Output '...'

    # Works, because PowerShell has already parsed all functions.
    Test-FunctionLoad
}

function Test-FunctionLoad { 

    Write-Output 'Test...'
}

# Invoke the entry point function.
Invoke-Main
```

Comment: @ZenoArrow You propably already know this way. I've added this answer mainly for people who find this question via search, see only the AST answer, and so would possibly use a more complicated solution than would actually be required.